# Doubts about Spring Boot microservice without entry point

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices, entry-point

Lately I found myself with a spring boot microservice maven project with a simple MVC (controller, service, repository) flow but without an entry point, i.e. without an annotated @SpringBootApplication class or a main method;

Now I'm not clear on the ways to make the microservice work and what the logical loop is that makes everything work.

The microservice in my case runs on a docker container and in the pom.xml file it has the declaration of a pom parent (I don't know if this last information has any relevance)

However, with these premises my question is to understand, having a spring project of this type, what are the different ways to use it and put it into operation, and above all, what is the reason that leads to this choice? What are the benefits if any?

I hope I have been as clear as possible, Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It is unclear without some example. A program has to have an entry point. If it's a container, how is it launched? With Spring, you can tell with the first line in the logs. You'll see `INFO 53986 --- [main] c.a.Application      : Starting Application using Java 11.0.15 on ...` Here, `c.a.Application#main` is the entry point.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Thanks for the comment, how it works in my case is unfortunately unclear to me (I only have access to the git repository where the microservice code is, startup will be managed somewhere in the CI/CD process I imagine, where I don't have access), so I still tried to ask a general question, that is, in which cases is this approach used and how does it all actually work?

Comment: Usage of "container" here is unclear. maybe you mean docker container? or servlet container? and who knows how this works, maybe this is set up with an old school web.xml that specifies a spring application context that is configured to do component scanning? are you even sure it is spring-boot? there is very little to go on here.

Comment: @NathanHughes by container I meant docker container; in the pom.xml I have the spring boot dependencies so I would say yes for this

Comment: However, I didn't ask you to tell me how it works in my case, I wrote the first lines to justify my question, the question to the community is the general one of how to make a microservice work without those entry points and if something like this makes sense.

Comment: ok. so the thing that has to have an entry point is tomcat (or jetty or whatever is serving your application code). the spring-boot entry point is there so that it can boot up tomcat. if you were deploying to a running application server then you wouldn't need a spring boot entry point. although it would still be useful for running locally and getting rid of it is crazy.

Comment: Ok, so if I have to deploy the microservice for example on an application server I may not have the entry point in spring boot, but if I had a main it wouldn't change anything anyway